# Custom Order By in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem in CakePHP

I have an array ($A) and its value

```
Array  // in $A
( 
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    ...
}
```

inside the controller:

```
$conditions[]=array('Room.place_id' =>$A,'Room.status'=>'1');

$this->paginate= array(

                'limit' =>50,

                'recursive' => 2,

                'conditions' => $conditions,

                );
```

now result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Room] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [place_id] => 1
                    [type] => place
                 )
               )
    [1] => Array
        (
             [Room] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [place_id] => 3
                 )
         ).
    ...
```

Now i want to order by (in Place id) using $A value ...

I want the first record to be the Room with [place_id] => 3  (because $a[0] = 3)

The second record should be the Room with [place_id] => 4 (because $a[1] = 4)
and so on

Comment: I don't see where you've tried to order anything.

Comment: I don't see any solution with the information provided. Of course you could sort using two "for" loops in the view. However this is a paginated list, so the sort should be made within the query or else the pagination will be useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In mysql you can order by specific field values, by using `ORDER BY FIELD`:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE place_id IN (3,1) ORDER BY FIELD(place_id, 3, 1);
```

This will order your rooms in the custom order you wanted (first those with `place_id=3` then those with  `place_id=1`).

To do it in cake:

```
$this->paginate= array(
   'order' => 'FIELD(Room.place_id, '.implode(',', $A).')',
   ...
```

I'm assuming that `$A` contains only numbers, otherwise you'll have to sanitize the values that go into the `FIELD` expression.

Comment: great .. its working fine ... thanks a lot :)

before i am using this 

'order' => 'FIELD(Room.place_id, '$A')',

Comment: This is a great start. Now in a Model with multiple fields, is there a better solution than writing it out by hand?
e.g. `public $order = "active DESC, FIELD(day_of_week, 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'), start_time";`

Answer (score 1):

The field1 will show only value with zero on top and you can also add orders on other column.

```
$this->paginate= array(
    'limit' =>50,
    'recursive' => 2,
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order' => "FIELD(field1, value) DESC , field2 DESC" // "FIELD(status, 2) DESC , id DESC"
);
```